# No texture displayed in 3D view

Tags: texturing, uv, 3d-view

I have followed many tutorials about UV map for textures to a mesh, but still can't see the texture in UV/Image Editor. I use Blender 2.70, This problem is present in Blender Render and also in Cycles Render logically with different procedures.

Comment: did you unwrap the object and assign material with this texture? it would be better if you can add screenshots or upload an example file

Comment: you can't see the texture in UV/image editor (as said) or in viewport 3D view?

Comment: You need to give more detail than this and provide a screenshot at least. Otherwise, it is difficult to tell what the cause of your problem is.

Answer (score 1):

That could happen if you are viewing the render result. Look at the bottom of the UV/Image Editor and see if it says “Render Result”.  If that is the problem, just click the X to the right of the image selection box or select another image and you should be able to see the unwrapped pelt.

[image]